# StackExchange.Redis causing high CPU usage on GET String

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have the following C# Class, a RedisCacheHelper, this class is being using in an ASP.Net
Web application, and called for every user that logs onto the Web Application:

I noticed that every user that accesses the application, and this causes the CPU to spike to 90%, I ran a monitor on the redis-cli and noticed that there's a GET every millisecond, which seems to result in extremely high CPU usage.

Is there anything that I can do to improve this performance issue?

StackExchange.Redis Version 2.1.58

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace RedisCacheLayer.RedisCacheHelper
{
    public static class RedisCacheHelper
    {
        private static IDatabase _database = null;
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            string cacheConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisCacheConfigUrl"].ToString();
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(cacheConnection);
        });

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }

        public static string GetString(string cacheKey)
        {
            if (_database == null)
                _database = Connection.GetDatabase();

            return _database.StringGet(cacheKey);
        }

        public static T Get<T>(string cacheKey)
        {
            var value = Connection.GetDatabase().StringGet(cacheKey);
            return Deserialize<T>(value);
        }

        public static void Set(string cacheKey, object cacheValue)
        {
            if (_database == null)
                _database = Connection.GetDatabase();

            _database.StringSet(cacheKey, Serialize(cacheValue));
        }

        public static void SetString(string cacheKey, string cacheValue)
        {
            if (_database == null)
                _database = Connection.GetDatabase();

            _database.StringSet(cacheKey, cacheValue);
        }

        private static byte[] Serialize(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            BinaryFormatter objBinaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            objBinaryFormatter.Binder = new PreMergeToMergedDeserializationBinder();
            using (MemoryStream objMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                objBinaryFormatter.Serialize(objMemoryStream, obj);
                byte[] objDataAsByte = objMemoryStream.ToArray();
                return objDataAsByte;
            }
        }

        private static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] bytes)
        {
            BinaryFormatter objBinaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            objBinaryFormatter.Binder = new PreMergeToMergedDeserializationBinder();
            if (bytes == null)
                return default(T);

            using (MemoryStream objMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                T result = (T)objBinaryFormatter.Deserialize(objMemoryStream);
                return result;
            }
        }

        public static bool HasKeys(string key)
        {
            return Connection.GetDatabase().KeyExists(key);
        }

        sealed class PreMergeToMergedDeserializationBinder : SerializationBinder
        {
            public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
            {
                Type typeToDeserialize = null;

                // For each assemblyName/typeName that you want to deserialize to
                // a different type, set typeToDeserialize to the desired type.
                String exeAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;


                // The following line of code returns the type.
                typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                    typeName, exeAssembly));

                return typeToDeserialize;
            }
        }

    }
}
```